# Change form from onRead to Edit through button

Tags: reactjs, forms, if-statement, button, input

This is user profile settings page: [Box](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-varahamihira-dbhco)

What I would like to do is have the input fields enabled and disable them once the Save button is pressed.
After this operation "edit" button becomes enable and pressing it also the input fields return enabled.

1)Profile Page --> Form `readOnly=disabled` and "Edit" `button=disabled` --> Fill in form --> Save --> Form `readOnly=enabled`and "Edit" `button=enabled`.

When a user save his info:

2)Form `readOnly=enabled` and "Edit" `button=enabled` --> Click "Edit" button ---> Form `readOnly=disabled` and "Save" `button=enabled` --> fill in form...

I reread the whole guide on reactjs.org but I can't solve the problem starting from the theory. Without practical examples I can't learn and I haven't found any by googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replicated your desired functionality in a code sandbox and added comments to help you understand what is going on.

Please take a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-rain-7nqwq?file=/src/Form.js

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It works , but only one problem: After that I click on "Save" bot "Edit" and "Save" buttons are enabled. If it is not a too long process I would be grateful if you could explain to me how to use a single button and show "save" or "edit" depending on the state.

Comment: So you want the save button to be disabled when edit button is enabled?

Comment: No, only 1 button. It starts "save", when you click on it it changes to "edit". Button is the same, basically I would like the functions you have already written to be possible on a single button that changes depending on the state.

Comment: I've updated the sandbox with additional comments. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

How to have read-only vs editing state:
You just need to have state to determine if you're editing or not, say `isEditing` - then set the fields disabled based on it. (Or swap the fields out for plain text displays or whatever)

The edit button would set `isEditing = true`, and the save button would set it back to false.

Comment: I thank you for the answer. I started studying coding for a very short time, without a practical example I can't understand how to do it.